# Adding key vault access permissions while preserving existing ones

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-keyvault

I have an Azure PowerShell task in my pipeline, in which I need to import a certificate to a key vault. Before doing that, I need to assign `Import` certificate permission to the current service principal. However, this service principal might already have existing certificate permissions (e.g. `Get`, `List`) from other tasks in this or other pipelines. If I use `Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy`, it will remove these other permissions. Is there a way of preserving these permissions, and just adding some new ones?

```
$spId = (Get-AzContext).Account.Id;
Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName $kv -ServicePrincipalName $spId -PermissionsToCertificates Import
Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $kv …
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way to add the new permission, your option is to get the old permissions as a list, add the new permission to it, then set all the permissions again.

The sample works for me:

```
$spId = (Get-AzContext).Account.Id
$objectid = (Get-AzADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $spId).Id
$kv = Get-AzKeyVault -ResourceGroupName <group-name> -VaultName joykeyvault 
$cerpermission = ($kv.AccessPolicies | Where-Object {$_.ObjectId -eq $objectid}).PermissionsToCertificates
$cerpermission += "Import"
Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName joykeyvault -ObjectId $objectid -BypassObjectIdValidation -PermissionsToCertificates $cerpermission
```

**Note**: The parameters in the last line is important, if your service principal used in the devops service connection does not have the permission to list service principals in your AAD tenant, please use `-ObjectId $objectid -BypassObjectIdValidation` instead of `-ServicePrincipalName $spId`, otherwise you will get an error.